# How to connect a PlayStation 3 to a computer monitor

Tags: windows-7, display

I have ordered a PS3 Super Slim 500GB console, and I plan on connecting it to my PC's monitor.

The monitor I have is the [Acer S221HQBD](http://www.acerdirect.co.uk/Acer_S221HQLbd_Super_Slim_LED_Monitor_21.5_inch_ET.WS1HE.008/version.asp), which does not have an HDMI port. So I would imagine that I could connect the PS3 to it using an HDMI to DVI connector.

After contacting my local PC megastore, I was advised that the setup would not work as the picture would be black and white, or not appear at all.

Is this true?

Comment: How are you going to get the audio out? I use a HDMI to DVI connector for my PC and it works fine but I also need to run an audio lead as DVI doesn't support audio

Comment: @JoeTaylor - The PS3 also comes with RCA, so the idea is that I will buy a converter which takes in the white and red wires and outputs into a 3.5mm female. So I'll connect the HDMI to DVI cable to the monitor, and the sound through the above mechanism. Are there problems with this approach?

Comment: Nope, that sounds solid to me. You could just get an RCA - 3.5mm Male audio lead and then only need 1 wire instead of a converter and a wire.

Comment: @JoeTaylor - Is your comment directed towards achieving sound? My speakers have a male which would need to be plugged into the female 3.5mm

Comment: Ah ok of course, I'm thinking of my setup where the monitor has an audio in so I use a male 3.5mm into it.

Comment: So there's no problem with the sound, but what about the HDMI to DVI setup? It sounds good in theory, but I have read that there can be problems with this

Comment: That monitor is HDCP so it should work fine. https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/989/~/hdmi-to-dvi-converters-on-ps3

Comment: I am pasting the email reply which I received from the retailer:

"Kindly note we have previously tested this setup and it does not work. You either get a black and white picture, or no picture at all.

You will need an HDMI TV monitor for a PS3. You can easily connect your speakers to a TV monitor for a better sound output."

To be honest, to me it looked like they were just trying to get me to buy a TV set, but I wanted to confirm as if they are right, I would have a huge problem as I'd have a PS3 on the way and no monitor to play it on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should work *if* its a HCDP compatible monitor - which the comments indicate this is. There's some anecdotal evidence on [Ars Openforums](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=230232), and no one indicates it not working, and certainly not being in black and white. [Sony says "While HDMI to DVI converters may be used with the PS3, they are not guaranteed to work and may cause picture problems"](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/989/~/hdmi-to-dvi-converters-on-ps3) - so while its not defintive, its plausible that you may have some issues. On the other hand, they don't say it *won't* work.

I'd be rather curious about the retailer's testing methods, and wonder if their cable was faulty in some odd way.

Answer (score -1):

You should read more about [HDMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Versions) and [DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Specifications).
Using HDMI to DVI connector will **never** give you the same quality.

Comment: Are you sure about that? As I've done some research and the quality loss seems to be barely noticeable in many cases. This link seems to back it up: http://www.gamespot.com/forums/topic/28337023/does-hdmi-to-dvi... 

Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to www.gamespot.com @DotNET

Comment: It's loading fine for me :/